# Unable to connect to Websocket from CloudRun

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-run

We have a backend developed with Golang using Fiber (gofiber) and used also Fiber's Websocket middleware.

When trying to connect from a Web client in local (ws://...) it works perfectly. When deploying our server to CloudRun, and trying to connect (ws://...) it returns a 400.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

WebSockets are currently not supported on Cloud Run fully managed. This is a highly requested feature, but it's not yet implemented.

However, running WebSockets currently works on [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup) because of its GCE-based native networking layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but In the documentation, it is stated that outbound requests Websocket communication is supported https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket

Comment: Yes, the websocket must be opened by Cloud Run (outbound part). An external client can't open a websocket on Cloud Run fully managed

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm still not sure how to initiate/open the connection from my backend (in Go). All examples are showing clients initiating the connections, and the <OnConnect> event being triggered. Any guidelines on this?

Comment: This info isn't correct anymore? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets

Comment: Cloud run supports WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a response code 400 (which means Bad Request), check your header or cookies.

Google Cloud run converts the header keys to lowercase characters

example:
`"Auth-Token"` converted to `"auth-token"`

Always use `wss://` instead of `ws://` for cloud run